# Recorrer una tabla con diversos inputs e imprimirlos en otra

Tags: javascript, jquery

He estado teniendo dificultades planeando la lógica para este problema.

Tengo una tabla con diversos tipos de `input` (*text,date,checklist*) y deseo imprimirlos en el orden dado por la primera tabla, pero tengo problemas cuando selecciono algunos `input`.

Este es el código HTML que estoy usando:

> **Actualizacion:** ¿Cómo podría guardar el segundo `date` de las vigencias y
>   guardar el `value` del `select`?

```js
$('#botones').click(function() {
  var values = [];

  $('#TableID input[class="chk"]:checked').each(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    values.push({
      eleccion: $(this).val(),
      especificacion: $(row).find("input[name=id]").val(),
      suma: $(row).find("input[name=cobertura_suma]").val(),
      plazo: $(row).find('option:selected').val(),/*Aqui quiero guardar el valor del select, pero no se como*/
      vigencia: $(row).find("input[name=cobertura_vigencia_ini] ").val(),
      gen: $(row).find("input[name=cobertura_vigencia_fin] ").val()/*no me deja sacar el valor de esta fecha*/

    });
  });
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tablaMaestra" id="tablaMaestra">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tipo de póliza <br>Marcar la opción(es)</th>
      <th>Moneda (Especificar)</th>
      <th>Suma Asegurada</th>
      <th>Plazo de vigencia <br>de la fianza</th>
      <th>Vigencia (desde / hasta)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TableID">
    <tr>

      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="poliza" value="seriedad" class="chk" id="chk">Seriedad de oferta
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <div class="cambio_dinero ">
          <select name="cobertura_moneda" id="cobertura_moneda" class="cobertura_moneda">
            <option value="S/">S/</option>
            <option value="$">$</option>
            <option value="£">£</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </td>

      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_suma" id="cobertura_suma" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>

      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_fianza" id="cobertura_fianza" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>

      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_ini" id="cobertura_vigencia_ini">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_fin" id="cobertura_vigencia_fin">
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td cclass="tipo_id[]"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="poliza" value="fiel">Fiel Cumplimiento</td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <select name="" id="cobertura_moneda" class="cobertura_moneda">
          <option value="soles">S/</option>
          <option value="dolar">$</option>
          <option value="euros">£</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_suma" id="cobertura_suma" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" id="cobertura_fianza" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_ini" id="cobertura_vigencia_ini">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_fin" id="cobertura_vigencia_fin">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tipo_id[]"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="poliza" value="directo">Adelanto Directo</td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <select name="" id="cobertura_moneda" class="cobertura_moneda">
          <option value="soles">S/</option>
          <option value="dolar">$</option>
          <option value="euros">£</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_suma" id="cobertura_suma" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" id="cobertura_fianza" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_ini" id="cobertura_vigencia_ini">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_fin" id="cobertura_vigencia_fin">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tipo_id[]"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="poliza" value="materiales">Adelanto para materiales</td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <select name="" id="cobertura_moneda" class="cobertura_moneda">
          <option value="soles">S/</option>
          <option value="dolar">$</option>
          <option value="euros">£</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_suma" id="cobertura_suma" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" id="cobertura_fianza" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_ini" id="cobertura_vigencia_ini">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_fin" id="cobertura_vigencia_fin">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tipo_id[]"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="poliza" value="otros">Otros(Especificar) <input type="text" class="opciones_otros" size="4" id="opciones_otros" placeholder="Especifique"></td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <select name="" id="cobertura_moneda" class="cobertura_moneda">
          <option value="soles">S/</option>
          <option value="dolar">$</option>
          <option value="euros">£</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_suma" id="cobertura_suma" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" id="cobertura_fianza" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_ini" id="cobertura_vigencia_ini">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_fin" id="cobertura_vigencia_fin">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="botones" class="botones">botones</button>

<div id="section-to-print">

  <table class="impresion">
    <div class="modelo clearfix">

      <tr class=" nuevo">
        <td>Tipo de póliza <br>Marcar la opción(es)</td>
        <td>Moneda (Especificar)</td>
        <td>Suma Asegurada</td>
        <td>Plazo de vigencia <br>de la fianza</td>
        <td>Vigencia (desde / hasta)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class=" nuevo">
        <td class="cober_poliza"></td>

        <td class="cober_moneda cober_dinero"></td>


        <td class="cober_suma"></td>
        <td class="cober_fianza"></td>
        <td class="cober_vigencia_ini cober_vigencia_fin"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class=" nuevo">
        <td class="cobertura_poliza1"></td>

        <td class="cober_moneda1 cober_dinero1"></td>

        <td class="cober_suma1"></td>
        <td class="cober_fianza1"></td>
        <td class="cober_vigencia_ini1 cober_vigencia_fin1"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class=" nuevo">
        <td class="cobertura_poliza2"></td>

        <td class="cober_moneda2 cober_dinero2"></td>

        <td class="cober_suma2"></td>
        <td class="cober_fianza2"></td>
        <td class="cober_vigencia_ini2 cober_vigencia_fin2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="nuevo">
        <td class="cobertura_poliza3"></td>

        <td class="cober_moneda3 cober_dinero3"></td>

        <td class="cober_suma3"></td>
        <td class="cober_fianza3"></td>
        <td class="cober_vigencia_ini3 cober_vigencia_fin3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="nuevo">
        <td class="cobertura_poliza4"></td>

        <td class="cober_moneda4 cober_dinero4"></td>

        <td class="cober_suma4"></td>
        <td class="cober_fianza4"></td>
        <td class="cober_vigencia_ini4 cober_vigencia_fin4"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>

  </div>
```

Comment: No se ve el código Javascript que usas, ni tampoco se entiende cuál es el problema en sí.

Comment: El problema tal vez sea que no tienes código javascript, para agregarlo debes hacerlo en una etiqueta script, aquí un tutorial de como hacerlo https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_scripts.asp

Comment: mil disculpas, me olvide colocar aqui el codigo, este fue el que plantee para almacenar los datos en un array (me falta el del selec) .

Comment: com imprimir te refieres a en una impresora o imprimirlo a consola?

Comment: De la primera tabla se deben registrar datos, y esos se imprimen (Se mandan) a otra tabla donde se veran los datos registrados. Lo de impresion en un printer ya se hacerlo, solo tengo problemas al querer obtener el valor de del select  y la segunda fecha *vigencia final* ,

Answer (score 2):

varias cosas:

1. Ojo con el `HTML`. Estás utilizando el mismo `id` para los mismos elementos en tus distintos `<tr>` (`cobertura_moneda`, `cobertura_vigencia_ini`, etc.). Ten en cuenta que los `ids` deben ser únicos. Por otra parte, estás definiendo el `name` de `cobertura_moneda` en el primer `select` pero no en los siguientes y a la hora de utilizar los selectores por `name` no te funcionará.
2. Selectores. Hay varios errores:

   - Aquí estás buscando un `input` cuyo nombre sea `id`:

   `$(row).find("input[name=id]").val()`

   Lo que deberías hacer es buscar un `select` (no es tipo input si no `select`) cuyo `name` sea `cobertura_moneda`. Y en concreto la `option` seleccionada ([más info](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) sobre selectores). Aquí he puesto que muestre el `.val()` pero podrías querer obtener el `.text()`

   `$(row).find("select[name=cobertura_moneda] option:selected").val()`

   - En este punto entiendo que quieres obtener el valor del `select` `cobertura_moneda`:

   `plazo: $(row).find('option:selected').val(),/*Aqui quiero guardar el valor del select, pero no se como*/`

En ese caso sería como he puesto antes:

```
$(row).find("select[name=cobertura_moneda] option:selected").val()
```

- Por último aquí no termino de entender el problema.

`gen: $(row).find("input[name=cobertura_vigencia_fin] ").val()/*no me deja sacar el valor de esta fecha*/`

Yo lo veo bien:

```
[
  {
    "eleccion": "seriedad",
    "especificacion": "S/",
    "suma": "234",
    "plazo": "S/",
    "vigencia": "2018-12-04",
    "gen": "2018-12-27"
  }
]
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcionando (los ids no los he cambiado para que sean únicos, habría que hacerlo):

```js
$('#botones').click(function() {
  let values = [];

  $('#TableID input[class="chk"]:checked').each(function() {
    let row = $(this).closest("tr");
    values.push({
      eleccion: $(this).val(),
      especificacion: $(row).find("select[name=cobertura_moneda] option:selected").val(),
      suma: $(row).find("input[name=cobertura_suma]").val(),
      plazo: $(row).find("select[name=cobertura_moneda] option:selected").val(),/*Aqui quiero guardar el valor del select, pero no se como*/
      vigencia: $(row).find("input[name=cobertura_vigencia_ini] ").val(),
      gen: $(row).find("input[name=cobertura_vigencia_fin] ").val()/*no me deja sacar el valor de esta fecha*/

    });
  });
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tablaMaestra" id="tablaMaestra">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tipo de póliza <br>Marcar la opción(es)</th>
      <th>Moneda (Especificar)</th>
      <th>Suma Asegurada</th>
      <th>Plazo de vigencia <br>de la fianza</th>
      <th>Vigencia (desde / hasta)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TableID">
    <tr>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="poliza" value="seriedad" class="chk" id="chk">Seriedad de oferta
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <div class="cambio_dinero ">
          <select name="cobertura_moneda" id="cobertura_moneda" class="cobertura_moneda">
            <option value="S/">S/</option>
            <option value="$">$</option>
            <option value="£">£</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </td>

      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_suma" id="cobertura_suma" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>

      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_fianza" id="cobertura_fianza" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>

      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_ini" id="cobertura_vigencia_ini">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_fin" id="cobertura_vigencia_fin">
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td cclass="tipo_id[]"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="poliza" value="fiel">Fiel Cumplimiento</td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <select name="cobertura_moneda" id="cobertura_moneda" class="cobertura_moneda">
          <option value="soles">S/</option>
          <option value="dolar">$</option>
          <option value="euros">£</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_suma" id="cobertura_suma" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" id="cobertura_fianza" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_ini" id="cobertura_vigencia_ini">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_fin" id="cobertura_vigencia_fin">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tipo_id[]"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="poliza" value="directo">Adelanto Directo</td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <select name="cobertura_moneda" id="cobertura_moneda" class="cobertura_moneda">
          <option value="soles">S/</option>
          <option value="dolar">$</option>
          <option value="euros">£</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_suma" id="cobertura_suma" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" id="cobertura_fianza" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_ini" id="cobertura_vigencia_ini">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_fin" id="cobertura_vigencia_fin">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tipo_id[]"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="poliza" value="materiales">Adelanto para materiales</td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <select name="cobertura_moneda" id="cobertura_moneda" class="cobertura_moneda">
          <option value="soles">S/</option>
          <option value="dolar">$</option>
          <option value="euros">£</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_suma" id="cobertura_suma" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" id="cobertura_fianza" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_ini" id="cobertura_vigencia_ini">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_fin" id="cobertura_vigencia_fin">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tipo_id[]"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="poliza" value="otros">Otros(Especificar) <input type="text" class="opciones_otros" size="4" id="opciones_otros" placeholder="Especifique"></td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <select name="cobertura_moneda" id="cobertura_moneda" class="cobertura_moneda">
          <option value="soles">S/</option>
          <option value="dolar">$</option>
          <option value="euros">£</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" name="cobertura_suma" id="cobertura_suma" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="text" id="cobertura_fianza" style="width:100px" class="cobertura">
      </td>
      <td class="tipo_id[]">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_ini" id="cobertura_vigencia_ini">
        <input type="date" name="cobertura_vigencia_fin" id="cobertura_vigencia_fin">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="botones" class="botones">botones</button>

<div id="section-to-print">

  <table class="impresion">
    <div class="modelo clearfix">

      <tr class=" nuevo">
        <td>Tipo de póliza <br>Marcar la opción(es)</td>
        <td>Moneda (Especificar)</td>
        <td>Suma Asegurada</td>
        <td>Plazo de vigencia <br>de la fianza</td>
        <td>Vigencia (desde / hasta)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class=" nuevo">
        <td class="cober_poliza"></td>

        <td class="cober_moneda cober_dinero"></td>


        <td class="cober_suma"></td>
        <td class="cober_fianza"></td>
        <td class="cober_vigencia_ini cober_vigencia_fin"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr class=" nuevo">
        <td class="cobertura_poliza1"></td>

        <td class="cober_moneda1 cober_dinero1"></td>

        <td class="cober_suma1"></td>
        <td class="cober_fianza1"></td>
        <td class="cober_vigencia_ini1 cober_vigencia_fin1"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class=" nuevo">
        <td class="cobertura_poliza2"></td>

        <td class="cober_moneda2 cober_dinero2"></td>

        <td class="cober_suma2"></td>
        <td class="cober_fianza2"></td>
        <td class="cober_vigencia_ini2 cober_vigencia_fin2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="nuevo">
        <td class="cobertura_poliza3"></td>

        <td class="cober_moneda3 cober_dinero3"></td>

        <td class="cober_suma3"></td>
        <td class="cober_fianza3"></td>
        <td class="cober_vigencia_ini3 cober_vigencia_fin3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="nuevo">
        <td class="cobertura_poliza4"></td>

        <td class="cober_moneda4 cober_dinero4"></td>

        <td class="cober_suma4"></td>
        <td class="cober_fianza4"></td>
        <td class="cober_vigencia_ini4 cober_vigencia_fin4"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>

  </div>
```